# Custom Prestashop Admin Module

Tags: templates, module, admin, prestashop

I am developing a module for prestashop (basically, it's a very custom import of data and the only thing I need is to have a form and process data). I have created controller class derived from the ModuleAdminController but the problem is where should I put the tpl file containing the look of my custom form?

I realize that I can put tpl file to the templates but I want to keep all files within my module folder, is it possible (probably somewhere like "/views/templates/admin")?

Answer (score 4):

This is **the most easy method** to create a basic admin controller / action in Prestashop 1.6

Create basic configuration :

**./config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<module>
    <name>foo</name>
    <displayName><![CDATA[Foo]]></displayName>
    <version><![CDATA[2.1.3]]></version>
    <description><![CDATA[Bar.]]></description>
    <author><![CDATA[your-name]]></author>
    <tab><![CDATA[administration]]></tab>
    <is_configurable>0</is_configurable>
    <need_instance>0</need_instance>
    <limited_countries></limited_countries>
</module>
```

**./foo.php**

```
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
    exit;

class BarcodeEasyPrint extends Module
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'foo';
        $this->tab = 'administration';
        $this->version = '1.0.0';
        $this->author = 'your-name-here';
        $this->need_instance = 0;
        $this->bootstrap = true;

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Foo');
        $this->description = $this->l('Bar.');

        if ((int)Tools::getValue('p'))
            $this->page = (int)Tools::getValue('p');
    }


}
```

You need to create the controller with base functions :

**./controllers/admin/AdminFooController.php**

```
class AdminFooController extends ModuleAdminController {


    public function __construct()   {
        $this->bootstrap = true;
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function createTemplate($tpl_name) {
        if (file_exists($this->getTemplatePath() . $tpl_name) && $this->viewAccess())
                return $this->context->smarty->createTemplate($this-    >getTemplatePath() . $tpl_name, $this->context->smarty);
            return parent::createTemplate($tpl_name);
    }

    public function initContent(){
        parent::initContent();
        $tpl = $this->createTemplate('content.tpl')->fetch();

        /* DO STUFF HERE */
        $posts = array();

        $this->context->smarty->assign('posts', $posts);

    }
}
```

You can use boostrap directly in the template file :

**./views/templates/admin/content.tpl**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I tested with other template name like configuration.tpl this code fails, we must add 
$tpl = $this->createTemplate('configuracion.tpl')->fetch();
 $this->context->smarty->assign('content', $tpl); // This line

Answer (score 3):

If it is an admin module only, then you will have no need to create any views. Because Prestashop provides a nice structure for admin section which is easy to use and we dont need to use any views or .tpl files. For admin section, normally three types of views or .tpl files are required, one for data display in grid, second for form and third for displaying a single record.

Prestashop already created .tpl files for them which you can find in  "admin_folder/themes/default/templates". In our controllers for admin, for form and for data grid, we just create arrays and PS handles to view the form and data grid according to the arrays we created.

So if you need a custom form at admin, then create a public function renderForm and create the form array in it, like below:

```
$this->fields_form = array(
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Video'),
            'image' => '../img/admin/tab-genders.gif'
        ),
        'input' => array(
            array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Video Title:'),
                'name' => 'title',
                'lang' => true,
                'size' => 70,
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!<>,;?=+()@#"�{}_$%:',
                'required' => true
            ),

            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'label' => $this->l('Video Code'),
                'name' => 'video_code',
                'rows' => 5,
                'cols' => 70,
                'desc' => $this->l('Place the embed code for the video')
            ),

        ),
        'submit' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Save'),
            'class' => 'button'
        )
    );

    return parent::renderForm();

} /* End of render member */
```

For other fields, checkout other prestashop admin controllers and you will see that how easily we can create forms in PS using that simple definitions in the arrays and we dont need to create .tpl files.

For front end, we can use the new modules MVC structure, where our module folder have sub folders for controllers (controllers/front, controllers/admin) , views and models .

Hope this will help you.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the helper form, here is the documentation for it, it is really easy to use ;) .

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/HelperForm

You also can find more information about how and where to use helper form, look for the function getContent() and displayForm().

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Creating+a+PrestaShop+module

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately any document not exist to point directly to solve this question but hear i have some URLs really useful and you should combine theme and get your realize:
http://presthemes.com/prestashop-news/modules-classes-and-controller-override-by-julien-breux-4.html

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Diving+into+PrestaShop+Core+development

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/New+Developers+Features+In+PrestaShop+1.5

http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-implement-a-controller.html

best regards

Answer (score 0):

extending the answer from @altafhussain create a folder views/templates/admin in your module and place your customview.tpl 
Than append the free text block as below.

```
$this->fields_form = array(
    'legend' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Legend')
    ),
    'input' => array(
          array(
                'type' => 'free',
                'label' => 'Whatever label text',
                'desc' => $this->display(__FILE__,'views/templates/admin/customview.tpl'),
                'name' => 'FREE_TEXT',
                'required' => false
        )

    ),
    'submit' => array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
        'class' => 'button'
    )
);

return parent::renderForm();
```

}